# Need Help: Integrals Involving Multi-Valued Functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, contour-integration, branch-cuts

I am trying to verify that $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx = -\frac{\pi}{4}$$
                                                                            [image]

using the above contour. I would appreciate detailed steps as I want to advance to problems that have roots on the positive real axis.

edit: Metamorphy recommended a wiki page that discusses this exact problem with loose steps, and I want to expand the problem for others.

To calculate this integral, one uses the function $$f(z) = \left( \frac{\log z}{z^2+1} \right)^2$$
and the branch of the logarithm corresponding to −π < arg z ≤ π (here I think $0$ < arg z < $2\pi$ is the same logic)

We will calculate the integral of f(z) along the keyhole contour shown above. As it turns out this integral is a multiple of the initial integral that we wish to calculate and by the Cauchy residue theorem we have
$$\left(\int_{\gamma_1}+\int_{\gamma_2}+\int_{\Gamma_1}+\int_{\Gamma_2}  \right)f(z)dz = 2\pi i\left(\sum Res \right) = 2\pi i\left( Res\left[\left( \frac{\log z}{z^2+1} \right)^2,i\right]+Res\left[\left( \frac{\log z}{z^2+1} \right)^2,-i\right] \right)$$
Let $\Gamma_2$ be the segment of radius R of the large circle, and $\Gamma_1$ be the segment of radius r of the small one. We will denote the upper line by $\gamma_1$, and the lower line by $\gamma_2$. As before we take the limit when R → ∞ and r → 0. The contributions from the two circles vanish.
We can easily show
$$Res\left[\left( \frac{\log z}{z^2+1} \right)^2,i\right] = \lim_{z\to i}\left[ \frac{d}{dz}\left( \frac{(z-i)^2}{(z-i)^2(z+i)^2}\log^2z \right) \right]$$
$$= \lim_{z\to i}\left[ \frac{d}{dz}\left( \frac{\log^2z}{(z+i)^2} \right) \right]$$
$$= \lim_{z\to i}\left[  \frac{2\log z}{z(z+i)^2}-\frac{2\log^2 z}{(z+i)^3} \right]$$
$$=   \frac{2\log i}{i(2i)^2}-\frac{2\log^2 i}{(2i)^3} $$
$$=   \frac{2\frac{\pi}{2}}{(-4)}+\frac{2\frac{i\pi^2}{4}}{8} $$
$$= -\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{i\pi^2}{16}$$
Similarly, we can show
$$Res\left[\left( \frac{\log z}{z^2+1} \right)^2,-i\right] =-\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{i\pi^2}{16}$$
where here you might be tempted to write $\log z = \log (-i) = \log (exp(i\frac{3\pi}{2})) = i\frac{3\pi}{2}$ but it is better to write $\log z = \log (-i) = \log (exp(-i\frac{\pi}{2})) = -i\frac{\pi}{2}$, which will give you the above equation. Using $z = exp(i\frac{3\pi}{2})$ we get
$$Res\left[\left( \frac{\log z}{z^2+1} \right)^2,-i\right] =\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac{9i\pi^2}{16}$$
and it's obvious which residue for $z=-i$ we should choose, though you would think both should work. We will proceed with the odd case; the other case can be followed in the wiki page.

We get
$$\left(\int_{\gamma_1}+\int_{\gamma_2}+\int_{\Gamma_1}+\int_{\Gamma_2}  \right)f(z)dz =2\pi i ( -\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{i\pi^2}{16}+\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac{9i\pi^2}{16})$$
$$=2\pi i(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{i\pi^2}{2})$$
$$=i\pi^2+\pi^3$$

In order to compute the contributions of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ we set z = x + iε on $\gamma_1$ and z = x − iε on $\gamma_2$ (notice the difference in z values since our contour is different than in the example), with 0 < x < ∞:
$$i\pi^2+\pi^3 = \left(\int_{\gamma_1}+\int_{\gamma_2}+\int_{\Gamma_1}+\int_{\Gamma_2}  \right)f(z)dz$$
$$= \left(\int_{\gamma_1}+\int_{\gamma_2}\right)f(z)dz$$
$$ = \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{\log (x+i\epsilon)}{1+(x+i\epsilon)^2} \right)^2dx  +\int_{\infty}^0 \left( \frac{\log (x-i\epsilon)}{1+(x-i\epsilon)^2} \right)^2dx $$
$$ = \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{\log (x+i\epsilon)}{1+(x+i\epsilon)^2} \right)^2  dx-\int_{0}^\infty \left( \frac{\log (x-i\epsilon)}{1+(x-i\epsilon)^2} \right)^2dx $$
$$ = \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{\log (x)}{1+x^2} \right)^2 dx -\int_{0}^\infty \left( \frac{\log (x)+2\pi i}{1+x^2} \right)^2dx$$
$$=\int_0^\infty \frac{4\pi^2}{(1+x^2)^2}dx - 4\pi i\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$
$$=4\pi^2(\frac{\pi}{4}) - 4\pi i\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$
$$=\pi^3 - 4\pi i I$$
so
$$i\pi^2 + \pi^3 = \pi^3 -4\pi i I$$
$$i\pi^2 = -4\pi i I$$
$$I = -\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Note: With the chosen contour, it appears you would not be able to use $\log -i = -i\frac{\pi}{2}$. This may be investigated in the future.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_5_%E2%80%93_the_square_of_the_logarithm), and pay attention to the *squaring* of the logarithm.

Comment: @metamorphy I am typing up the example with elaboration. Do you have any suggestions as I proceed with the odd case to show the choice of angle is arbitrary?

Comment: If you choose $\arg z \in (-\pi, \pi]$, the integrand is not a function with isolated singularities inside the contour and, besides, the integrals over $(i0, \infty + i0)$ and over $(-i0, \infty - i0)$ are the same. If you choose $\arg z \in [0, 2 \pi)$, then
$$\operatorname* {Res}_{z = i} f(z) =
-\frac \pi 4 + \frac {\pi^2 i} {16},
\quad \operatorname* {Res}_{z = -i} f(z) =
\frac {3 \pi} 4 - \frac {9 \pi^2 i} {16}.$$

Comment: @Maxim Right, that's what I got above. I am going to finish the math once I finish some work tonight, but it looks suspect.

Comment: @Maxim I've come to another dead end. Will you give my work a look?

Comment: @Maxim solved, thanks for your help.